# Vaadin panels not displaying correctly

Tags: vaadin

Hi I am trying to created 2 panels, one as a sidebar and the other as a content panel but they are not displaying correctly. There is a huge white space between the 2 panels. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
HorizontalLayout mainlayout = new HorizontalLayout();
mainlayout.setSizeFull();

Panel sidepanel = new Panel();
sidepanel.addStyleName(ValoTheme.PANEL_BORDERLESS);
sidepanel.setHeight("100%");
sidepanel.setWidth("20%");      

Panel content = new Panel();
content.addStyleName(ValoTheme.PANEL_BORDERLESS);
content.setHeight("100%");
content.setWidth("80%");

mainlayout.addComponent(sidepanel);
mainlayout.addComponent(content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HorizontalLayout mainlayout = new HorizontalLayout();
mainlayout.setSizeFull();

Panel sidepanel = new Panel();
sidepanel.addStyleName(ValoTheme.PANEL_BORDERLESS);

Panel content = new Panel();
content.addStyleName(ValoTheme.PANEL_BORDERLESS);

mainlayout.addComponent(sidepanel);
mainlayout.addComponent(content);

mainlayout.setExpandRatio(sidepanel, 2);
mainlayout.setExpandRatio(content, 8);
```

Comment: figured it out shortly after i posted but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Set both panels to 100% size.
Then set the expand ratio of the parent layout to 20 and 80.

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractOrderedLayout.html#setExpandRatio%28com.vaadin.ui.Component,%20float%29